# How to do if condition plus dict on helm template?

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to do an if condition in a template that already have a dict like:
`{{dict ... }}`

Not sure if it's possible to do an if condition before the dict like:
`{{- if .Value... dict ...}}`

I've tried a couple shoots on something like that and didn't work actually.
Does anyone knows whether it's possible to do that?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of your existing template?  Can you describe the logic you want in some other language?  (Many things are possible – the template language has a lot of power – but not necessarily everything, and the syntax can be complicated.)

Comment: I actually don't know how to describe this in other languages. But for better explanation, the template that is already in the code has dict that contains a couple of values that is used by liveness and readiness probe from values.yaml. But I have to include a conditional that checks if liveness and readiness are enabled. In the values is enabled true but I must include something like ```{{- if .Values.pod.probes.readiness.enabled}}``` that will check before the dict.

Comment: Unusually for the template language, the [dictionary functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) are able to mutate a map object; does this help you?  Even just writing out the logic in prose would help; something like "if this value is set then the dictionary should contain this key, otherwise it shouldn't".

Answer (score 1):

```
  {{- range $k, $v :=  .Values.dict }}
  {{- if eq "aaa" k }}
  {{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```